# Toggle button not working in accordion, made using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

## HTML

I want to insert FAQ question in div of class "section-center"

```
<body>

    <section class="questions">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>FAQ SECTION</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="section-center">
<!-- dynamic data insert here -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- script -->
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

## CSS

Here with the help of js we will add/remove "show-text" class. When the "show-text" is added. 'question-text' class will have display block (answer of the question will be visible) , 'minus-icon' class will have display inline(minus icon will be visible which was initially hidden) and 'plus-icon' will have display none (plus icon will be visible).

```
.question-text {
    display: none;
}

.show-text .question-text {
    display: block;
}

.minus-icon {
    display: none;
}

.show-text .minus-icon {
    display: inline;
}

.show-text .plus-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

## JS

This is the array of question and answer

```js
const faq = [
  {
    ques: 'this is test question',
    answer: 'this is test answer ',
  },
  {
    ques: 'this is test question',
    answer: 'this is test answer ',
  },
]
```

traversing the DOM where we want to insert the question/answer.

```js
const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');
```

as the webpage loads displayQuestion function is called to display the question answer.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  displayQuestions(faq);
});

const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');

//console.log(questions);
```

this part of code allows the functionality of automatically closing the opened question, when next question is open by clicking a toggle button.

```js
questions.forEach((question) => {
  const btn = question.querySelector('.question-btn');

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    questions.forEach((curQuestion) => {
      if (curQuestion !== question) {
        curQuestion.classList.remove('show-text');
      }
    });
    question.classList.toggle('show-text');
  });
});
```

function to display question/answer

```js
// function to display questions

function displayQuestions(items) {
  let display = items.map(({ ques, answer }) => {
    return ` 
            <article class="question">
                <div class="question-title">
                    <P>${ques}</P>
                    <button type="button" class="question-btn">
                        <span class="plus-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                        </span>

                        <span class="minus-icon">
                            <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div> 
                
                 <div class="question-text">
                    <p>${answer}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
          `;
  });
  display = display.join('');
  //   console.log(display);
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = display;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of the code in a form where one can reproduce the situation. A [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) would be ideal. Note that there is little reason to use JavaScript for accordions: the `summary` and `detail` HTML elements can perform the same effect.

Comment: Does the `const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');` code and the `questions.forEach` code run before `displayQuestions` is called? It looks like they probably do, in which case there's nothing for the `questions.forEach` to work on. Note: the order of the code is not going to determine when `displayQuestions` is called because this code gets called by an event handler at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've moved the code relating to adding event listeners to the question buttons into a function called `addEventListenersToQuestions` and called this after `displayQuestions` is run in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener callback function.

The reason is that although the code for adding to event listeners to the buttons was after the `displayQuestions` code in source order it was actually being run before `displayQuestions` had run. In JS event listener callbacks will only run at some time after the current section of code that's being executed.

```js
const faq = [
  {
    ques: 'this is test question 1',
    answer: 'this is test answer 1',
  },
  {
    ques: 'this is test question 2',
    answer: 'this is test answer 2',
  },
];

const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  displayQuestions(faq);
  addEventListenersToQuestions();
});


function addEventListenersToQuestions() {
  const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');

  questions.forEach((question) => {
    const btn = question.querySelector('.question-btn');

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      questions.forEach((curQuestion) => {
        if (curQuestion !== question) {
          curQuestion.classList.remove('show-text');
        }
      });
      question.classList.toggle('show-text');
    });
  });
}

// function to display questions

function displayQuestions(items) {
  let display = items.map(({ ques, answer }) => {
    return ` 
            <article class="question">
                <div class="question-title">
                    <P>${ques}</P>
                    <button type="button" class="question-btn">
                        <span class="plus-icon">
                            +
                        </span>

                        <span class="minus-icon">
                            -
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div> 
                
                 <div class="question-text">
                    <p>${answer}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
          `;
  });
  display = display.join('');
  //   console.log(display);
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = display;
}
```

```css
.question-text {
    display: none;
}

.show-text .question-text {
    display: block;
}

.minus-icon {
    display: none;
}

.show-text .minus-icon {
    display: inline;
}

.show-text .plus-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="questions">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>FAQ SECTION</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section-center">
<!-- dynamic data insert here -->
    </div>
</section>
```